# Javascript - Showing an alert box on a specific date

Tags: javascript

I want to show an alert box, which will only appear on a specific date.

```
<script>
  alert('Registration Time is Over !!!');
</script>
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: `if date == specific_date alert()` ?

Comment: Do you expect your page to be opened for multiple days straight? If no you could simply check current date  `new Date()` to equal the "specific date".

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var alertdate = "12/18/2018";
var alerttext = "Registration time is over!";
var d = new Date();
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
} 

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
if(today == alertdate){
alert(alerttext)
}
</script>
```

Change alertdate to your date in the following format:
Month/Day/Year
Change alerttext to the text you want.

Answer (score -1):

Use a timeout.

```
var currentDateMillis = new Date().getTime(); // Get time on millis
var alarmDateMillis = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds).getTime();

if (alarmDateMillis > currentDateMillis)
   setTimeout (alarm, alarmDateMillis - currentDate);
else // This is in case you want it to be shown even after the date
   alarm();

function alarm () {
   alert('Registration Time is Over !!!');
}
```